# Why doesn't Ubuntu use YaST?

Tags: configuration, system

openSUSE is known by it's YaST control center, a powerful tool that centralizes all the system configurations. It makes it a lot simpler to configure the system, why doesn't Ubuntu make use of such a thing?

[image]

Comment: Also YAST is slow.

Answer (score 12):

YaST was built to work with RPM packages, one of the two most popular package formats. Ubuntu, along with all Debian variants, use DEB packages and their related tools (dpkg/apt) for package management. Also, as another user mentioned, there are functional replacements for most (all?) of YaSTs features in [synaptic](http://packages.ubuntu.com/synaptic) , [aptitude](http://packages.ubuntu.com/aptitude), and [software-center](http://packages.ubuntu.com/software-center). Most of YaST's configuration functionality is present in GNOME as far as I am aware.

Comment: Yast is not only for package managment.

Answer (score 3):

I know its not YAST but control centre can handle almost all the Preferences on a Gnome environment.

Gnome has its own control centre which is disabled on ubuntu by default but you can enable it.

**System > preferences > main menu**
Now go to the system tab and check box on **control central** and close

Now the control centre should be available under places menu, there you **can set preferences for almost all the applications on ubuntu**.