# How do I use a Genius webcam under Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: usb, webcam

I'm trying to use an old webcam that I have under Ubuntu 16.04, and after doing the [steps of this guide](http://www.linuxintro.org/wiki/Set_up_a_Webcam_with_Linux), the results in the terminal are these:

```
33: USB 00.0: 0000 Unclassified device
[Created at usb.122]
Unique ID: FKGF.4j2b6xB9In8
Parent ID: pBe4.9T1GDCLyFd9
SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0
SysFS BusID: 2-1:1.0
Hardware Class: unknown
Model: "KYE WebCAM USB2.0"
Hotplug: USB
Vendor: usb 0x0458 "KYE Systems"
Device: usb 0x7012 "WebCAM USB2.0"
Revision: "1.02"
Speed: 480 Mbps
Module Alias: "usb:v0458p7012d0102dc00dsc00dp00icFFiscFFipFFin00"
Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
Attached to: #32 (Hub)
```

I don't want to do the rest («yast -i uvcvideo_kmp_default
modprobe uvcvideo») bc I already have the webcam of the laptop. But I wanted to use this other webcam bc it seems that it's still useable **(the light turns on when I plug it to the usb port)**.

*Additional details:*

1. The real model of the USB webcam is [Genius VideoCAM Slim USB 2](https://www.cnet.com/products/genius-videocam-slim-usb2-web-camera/specs/).
2. When I put this command in the terminal `ls -ltr /dev/video*` the result is `crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 0 nov 10 18:14 /dev/video0` which is the webcam integrated to my laptop.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu.com! As [Ubuntu doesn't use yast](http://askubuntu.com/questions/13216/why-doesnt-ubuntu-use-yast) it's fine that you don't want to do that. Here's a related question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/561892/configure-webcam